# Compile error when inheriting from class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, msbuild, mvvmcross

This is my class called `BoolToVisibilityValueConverter`:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, ViewStates>
{
    protected override ViewStates Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value ? ViewStates.Visible : ViewStates.Gone;
    }

    protected override bool ConvertBack(ViewStates value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ViewStates.Visible == value;
    }
}
```

It inherits from `MvxValueConverter` which is a generic class taking parameters `From` and `To`. The source of the `MvxValueConverter` can be found on Github under MvvmCross' repository - [MvxValueConverter](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/f7fcf18d960f578b851837f2aaaeb4d0e3b72364/MvvmCross/Platform/Platform/Converters/MvxValueConverter.cs).

I can build the project, run it and see it works. I am using Visual Studio 2015 with the latest Xamarin and the latest version of MvvmCross (4.0.0)

However, on our TeamCity server same build fails:

> [14:40:06][Csc] ValueConverters\BoolToVisibilityValueConverter.cs(10,
>   33): error CS0115:
>   'MyProject.Droid.ValueConverters.BoolToVisibilityValueConverter.Convert(bool,
>   System.Type, object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)': no suitable
>   method found to override
>
> [14:40:06][Csc] ValueConverters\BoolToVisibilityValueConverter.cs(15,
>   27): error CS0115:
>   'MyProject.Droid.ValueConverters.BoolToVisibilityValueConverter.ConvertBack(Android.Views.ViewStates,
>   System.Type, object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)': no suitable
>   method found to override

Error `CS0115` from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb57z28f.aspx) happens when `A method was marked as an override, but the compiler found no method to override`. The TeamCity has Visual Studio 2013 installed.

Why does my build fail?

Comment: @CarbineCoder does it really matter what it is for? I have provided the source code of it, you can see it easily. I am using MvvmCross and that is the converter to use when data-binding. How is it not included in my project when I clean, build and run it on my device (and it works)? The assembly is referenced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open your android projects .csproj file, and manually add a reference to System.Globalization